# reload behaves different in python 2 and 3

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, reload

In python 2:

```
import math
print(math.pi)
3.14159265359
math.pi = 2
print(math.pi)
2
reload(math)
print(math.pi)
3.14159265359
```

Now in python 3:

```
import math
print(math.pi)
3.141592653589793
math.pi=2
print(math.pi)
2
from importlib import reload
reload(math)
print(math.pi)
2
```

I was expecting the reload to reset the value of pi in the math library.
What do I wrong with the reload in python 3?

Comment: Which python shell you using?

Comment: python session from a Linux terminal. The same occurred from an OSX terminal.

Comment: It's true that the module does not seem to get reloaded. Perhaps this answer gives some insight https://stackoverflow.com/a/438845/1391441 as to why it isn't working?